# How do I add a command (tkinter) in an if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, command

I have created an if statement to check if the username and password and username entered is the same to the username and password in the textile. I have been able to display if the data inputted is correct or not. I now want to add a command into the if statement e.g. command = main_menu if the data inputted is correct (I am using tkinter)

This is the if code I have so far:

```
def validation(username1, password1):
    file = open("Accounts.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        line = line.split("\n")
        line = line[0].split(" ")

        if username1 == line[0] and password1 == line[1]:
            valid = Label(root, text="Data: Found")
            valid.place(x=290, y=130)
        else:
            valid = Label(root, text="Data: Not found")
            valid.place(x=280, y=130)

    file.close()
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks xx

Comment: A command for what? Is there a button that you want to associate it with?

Comment: if the username and password inputted are the same to the ones in the text file I want the main menu page to open. I am basically validating the username and password and if they are correct they can then play the game

Comment: What is `main_menu`? Can you just call it? (`main_menu()`)? Or is it a tkinter element? You need to make sure that you've supplied enough information for people to be able to help you.

Comment: main_menu is a function x

Comment: In that case, as also stated previously, you may simply call the function like this `main_menu()` if your condition is satisfied. Also, you can pass the the parameters in the function call, if any.